# Why IN clause in db2 not working in my database query

Tags: sql, db2

Maybe some of you will have an idea what's wrong. Explain why the `IN` clause does not work in DB2 when I have a string inside. For example:

```
WHERE CODE IN ('123', '234', '345')
```

Does not return anything. But when I put a number at the beginning, e.g. 0:```

```
WHERE CODE IN (0, '123', '234', '345')
```

suddenly, for all values specified in the `IN` clause, the data begins to be returned.
Magic. I do not know what's going on.
Please help.

Comment: Believe me the IN clause is working. But you should check and extent your query with the data types used. What type is the code column?

Comment: This column is of the VARCHAR type but it's content are numbers.

Comment: Please, provide the result of the following statement: `SELECT '*' || CODE || '*' FROM MYTAB WHERE CODE IN (0, '123', '234', '345')`

Answer (score 3):

You may look at the `Optimized Statement:` section of an access plan to understand what happens. Db2 executes your statement in such a rewritten form always.
Consider the following example:

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.TEST (CODE VARCHAR(10)) WITH REPLACE ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS NOT LOGGED;
INSERT INTO SESSION.TEST VALUES '123.';

EXPLAIN ALL FOR
SELECT CODE
FROM SESSION.TEST
WHERE CODE IN (
--0, 
'123', '234', '345'
);
```

> db2exfmt -d mydb -1 -o access_plan.txt

An optimized `Optimized Statement` section for this statement looks like:

```
Optimized Statement:
-------------------
SELECT 
  Q3.CODE AS "CODE" 
FROM 
  SESSION.TEST AS Q3 
WHERE 
  Q3.CODE IN ('123', '234', '345')
```

If you uncomment the commented out line, you get the following:

```
Optimized Statement:
-------------------
SELECT 
  Q1.CODE AS "CODE" 
FROM 
  SESSION.TEST AS Q1 
WHERE 
  DECFLOAT(Q1.CODE, 34) IN (0, 123, 234, 345)
```

So, as you see, Db2 does implicit data types conversion, and this is why you get different results.
The rules for resulting data types for operands using Numeric & String data types are described in [Rules for result data types](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008480.html) in the `Table 2. Operands and the resulting data type` table.

Answer (score 2):

I could imagine this happening if your `code` where a string of digits.  And, it contained values such as:

```
00123
123.0
```

In this case, with the values as strings, the comparison is as a string and there is no direct match.

Just adding one number to the `IN` list changes the list to numbers.  If you had something like `'abc'`, you would get a type conversion error.

Then that changes the conversion to numeric.  And when converted to numbers, some strings -- that would not match as strings -- might match as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Run the query with. It should fix it for you.

```
WHERE CODE IN (0, 123, 234, 345)
```